# Nested for-loop: why is the inner loop only executed once?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested, reverse

I'm confused about the use of a double for loop in python, this is my code:

```
import numpy as np

range1 = np.linspace(1,6,10)
range2 = reversed(np.linspace(1,6,10))

for t1 in range1:
    print t1
    for t2 in range2:
        print t1,t2
```

The output is this:

```
1.0
1.0 6.0
1.0 5.44444444444
1.0 4.88888888889
1.0 4.33333333333
1.0 3.77777777778
1.0 3.22222222222
1.0 2.66666666667
1.0 2.11111111111
1.0 1.55555555556
1.0 1.0
1.55555555556
2.11111111111
2.66666666667
3.22222222222
3.77777777778
4.33333333333
4.88888888889
5.44444444444
6.0
```

It only executes the inner loop for the first value of the outer loop, why is this happening? How can I get it to loop over all combinations of the first and second variable?

Answer (score 11):

`reversed()` produces an *iterator*; once you reach the end of an iterator, you can't re-use it:

```
>>> it = reversed([1, 2, 3])
>>> list(it)
[3, 2, 1]
>>> list(it)
[]
```

Create a new iterator for the nested loop:

```
for t1 in range1:
    print t1
    for t2 in reversed(range1):
        print t1,t2
```

The [`reversed()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) links to the [*iterator* glossary entry](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator):

> When no more data are available a `StopIteration` exception is raised instead. **At this point, the iterator object is exhausted** and any further calls to its `__next__()` method just raise `StopIteration` again.

Bold emphasis mine.

Comment: It's not always a generator. If the class implements `__reversed__` it can return practically anything. But for `np.array` you're correct!

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't that suffer from the same problem by consuming `range1` during the first inner loop, leaving nothing for the outer loop?

Comment: @MSeifert: the [`__reversed__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__) requires that an iterator is returned.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: `range1` is not an iterator; it's a numpy array (a sequence).

Comment: @MartijnPieters But that's not enforced. I [just tried it](https://gist.github.com/MSeifert04/13e2b3cf434f6f67c81be52a62168b0c) after reading your answer :)

Comment: Ah, OK. But still - I just tested it - it even works if it *is* a generator. I did `range1 = range(10)` (in Python 3), and your program ran as "expected". Isn't this strange?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: `range()` is a sequence, not a generator, see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges): *The `range` type represents an immutable sequence of numbers*.

Comment: Is there a performance impact in calling `reversed()` every loop compared to storing range2 in a list before the outer loop?

Comment: @MartijnPieters `isinstance(reversed([]), types.GeneratorType)` returns `False` for me, were you informal when using the generator term?

Comment: @Jérôme: you **have** to create a new iterator, there is no option here. Producing an iterator is cheap, it's just memory for a reference to the original sequence and an index.

Comment: @Jérôme Of course there's a performance impact. That's why one generally "reverses" numpy arrays using slicing: `[::-1]`.

Comment: @timgeb: I already corrected my terminology. A generator is an iterator implemented as a Python function.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: @MSeifert: Using a slice is more expensive because then you create a full copy.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, basic slicing on numpy arrays returns a **view** (not a copy). Practically for free.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah, I saw that edit too late. What about generator comprehensions?

Comment: @MartijnPieters you don't **have** to create a new iterator, you can consume the iterator in a list before the outer loop (see my answer). I guess the trade-off is that there is a small overhead in recreating an iterator each time (your solution), but if the length is huge, creating a list (my solution) can be an issue. Is that it?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: again, that's just syntax that produces an iterator, much like a generator.

Comment: @Jérôme: exactly. Creating a full copy of the list has a memory cost that `reversed` avoids. That can be a price that's worth paying of course. But when you do use `reversed()`, you have to create a new one in the loop each time.

Answer (score 5):

In every implementation that respects pythons data model the result of `reversed` can only be exhausted once (because it *should* return an iterator that is exhausted after the first traversal). After that iterator is exhausted it won't `yield` any items anymore. But you can simply reverse your array using slicing:

```
range2 = np.linspace(1,6,10)[::-1]

for t1 in range1:
    print t1
    for t2 in range2:
        print t1,t2
```

Basic slicing for `numpy.array`s is very performant, it doesn't even need to copy the original.

Given that you use `array`s you should be aware that iterating over them is a very slow operation because every value needs to be unboxed during the iteration. If you **really need** to iterate over one-dimensional `array`s (hint: you generally don't) you should convert them to `list`s:

```
range1 = np.linspace(1,6,10).tolist()
range2 = np.linspace(1,6,10)[::-1].tolist()
```

Because `tolist` is more efficient at the unboxing compared to the (implicit) unboxing in a `for`-loop.

Answer (score 3):

`reversed` returns a iterator. An iterator can only be consumed once.

You consume that iterator during the first iteration.

To use an iterator several times, you can store it in a `list`:

```
import numpy as np

range1 = np.linspace(1,6,10)
range2 = list(reversed(np.linspace(1,6,10)))  # store in list

for t1 in range1:
    print t1
    for t2 in range2:
        print t1,t2
```

One of the benefit of iterators is that the whole list is never computed. You can iterate over 1 million elements without creating the whole `[0, 1, ..., 1000000]` list, which is even better if your algorithm expects to break out of the loop when a condition is fulfilled.

In a simple case like in the OP, the list is short and you know you will be iterating over all the elements, so using a list is simple and efficient enough.